# How to draw a 3-D plot with 3 input variables as well as somewhere infinite in R?

Tags: r, 3d

I am writing a log-likelihood surface for the function:

ln[Pr(Y_A=186,Y_B=38,Y_{AB}=13,Y_O=284)]

= ln(G+186*ln(A^2+2*A*O)+38*ln(B^2+2*B*O)+13*ln(2*A*B)+284*ln(O^2))

Thanks to one answerer, I have changed my code to the following but facing new problems:

```
A = seq(0.0001, .9999,length=50)
B = A
O = A
G = 1.129675e-06   
f = function(A,B,O){F = ifelse(A+B+O==1,
                    G+186*log(A*A+2*A*O)+38*log(B*B+2*B*O)+13*log(2*A*B)+284*log(O*O), O)}
Z <- outer(A, B, O, f)
png()
persp(A,B,Z, theta=60, phi=30 )
dev.off()
```

The error told me that there isn't object "O".

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir)
```

What I mean to do is to input A, B and O under the constraint that A+B+O=1, and then to plot the log-likelihood surface letting A:x-axis, B:y-axis, log-likelihood:z-axis.

I **cannot** get rid of "O" cause the instruction commands that the parameter of the function should be a 3-dimensional vector: A,B,O.

So what should I do to improve my current code?
If I need to change a function, can anyone suggest a function to use?
(I think maybe I can use barycentric coordinates but I consider it as the last thing I want to do.)

Comment: If you want tested code you will open up your questions using [edit] and improve it. You have not defineg G. In fact, you should start R with a blank session and test the code every time *before* posting a question.

Comment: One problem is that you've used `f` in your `persp()` call where I think you meant to use `Z`. Otherwise, you can just set a lower limit for `Z` so it doesn't go all the way down to infinity, e.g. `persp(A,B,Z, zlim = c(-2000, max(Z, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to avoid regions of A and B where you know you will get into trouble. And use Z rather than `f` for the z-argument:

```
A = seq(0.0001, .9999,length=50)
B = A
G=1   # throws an error if not foundf
f = function(A,B){O <- 1-A-B; O <- ifelse(O==0, 0.00000001, O)
G+186*log(A*A+2*A*O)+38*log(B*B+2*B*O)+13*log(2*A*B)+284*log(O*O)}
Z <- outer(A, B, f)
png(); persp(A,B,Z, theta=60, phi=30 ); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after I cleared up the global environment and just copied your code to run, Rstudio still remind me that I produced NaNs.

Comment: Yep. I saw the warnings, too. The NA's are the reason that the high B + high A region is empty. NA's do not cause a plotting error, rather there will be nothing plotted where they occur. You are not explaining your current problem, despite the fact that you've been shown what was causing your error conditions. Two-thirds of the Z values are finite, one-third are NA.